# Display username in the profile section in the navbar

Tags: node.js, angular, asynchronous, subscribe

I'm trying to display the username in the navbar. I managed to do it using my profile service like this:

`let user of profileService.getProfile()`, which uses the subscribe in order to retrieve the data.

However, the first time that I log in the name won't pop out. If I refresh the browser, the name will be displayed. I guess that it has something to do with the subscribe and its asynchronous nature, but if that's the case, what would be the best solution to the problem?

Comment: Is the profile information stored in localStorage? Where and when are you setting the information i.e. `profileService.setProfile()` which is then used to `getProfile()`

Comment: No, I don't store the information into the localStorage. What I have is directly the getProfile which is the http method that calls the api. The api returns a json with the information that I need. However, the http get method returns another type (I think Observable) and the only way that I found to "get" (but not store it into a variable, which I'd prefer) the information is the subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can create a BehaviorSubject in service, it has a method getValue() that give a current value :

```
user$ : BehaviorSubject<String> = new BehaviorSubject("");

setProfile() {
    this.user$.next("newName");
}

getProfile(): string {
    return this.user$.getValue();
}
```

In View, you can use a pipe (AsyncPipe) to subscribe observable like :

```
{{ userOfProfileService$ | async }}
```

However, you can also use Subject observable without getProfile() but just with AsyncPipe in view.

```
    user$ : Subject<String> = new Subject();
```

Comment: I'm using my api, so the profileService uses http to get the information, so I'm not sure I could use this(?)

Comment: In setProfile() you can request api and in subscribe write this.user.next("newName");

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm kinda new to Angular/js/async...

Comment: setprofile() { this.http.get<string>(urlGetProfile).subscribe(result => this.user.next("newName")) } And welcome in the new world 

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comment your `getProfile()` returns an observable.
You can `subscribe` to it in your component  and then display the user name in your HTML component:

```js
userName: string;

constructor(private profileService: ProfileService){}

ngOnInit(): void { 
   this.profileService.getProfile().subscribe((resp)=>{
      //Assuming response only returns username
      this.userName = resp;
   });
}
```

and then in your HTML you can just bind to userName.

```
 <div>
    Logged in user name is: {{userName}} 
 </div>
```